# DateAdd function applied to TextBox value shows date from 1900 in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dateadd

I have code to compare user input with the date that must be in a textbox.

```vb
Dim tddate As Date
Dim expdate As String
Dim inputdate As String

tddate = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("pdate").Value
inputdate = TextBox1.Value
expdate = Format(DateAdd("m", 18, tddate), "dd/mm/yyyy")

If inputdate = expdate Then
    Range("A1").Value = TextBox1.Value
Else
    MsgBox "Input the correct date"
    Cancel = True
End If
```

Until yesterday it worked.

Today if I `Debug.Print` the `expdate` variable it shows 30/06/1901.
If I `Debug.Print Now` it shows the correct date.

I am using Excel 2019.
I tried the workbook on a different laptop with Excel 2016 and it shows the same thing.

Comment: So you are working with dates and compare strings with each other? I would advice to make them all dates to ensure you do not run into conversion issues..

Comment: When I look at the code I expect tddate is 1/1/1900, you add 18 months on top of this so you get 30/06/1901

Answer (score 2):

Try working with true date values, not text:

```vb
Dim tddate      As Date
Dim expdate     As Date
Dim inputdate   As Date

tddate = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("pdate").Value
If IsDate(TextBox1.Value) Then
    inputdate = DateValue(TextBox1.Value)
    expdate = DateAdd("m", 18, tddate)
    If DateDiff("d", inputdate, expdate) = 0 Then
        Range("A1").Value = inputdate
    Else
        Cancel = True
    End If
Else
    Cancel = True
End If

If Cancel Then
    MsgBox "Input the correct date"
End If
```